# Wordpress style ninjas forms emails

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

I want to create a custom HTML email template for my Ninja forms plugin forms but I'm unsure how to go about this. I've found some tutorials on how to customise WordPress emails but none seem to affect the Ninja forms emails.

To clarify I'm looking for a way to create a template that all Ninja forms emails will use - rather than entering the HTML into the CMS for each form.

Answer (score 0):

This plugin will do the job. You can easily style the mail but you can also create your own template.

https://nl.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-html-mail/

Answer (score 0):

A good idea is to use inline CSS under 'Emails & Actions -> Email(Type) -> EMAIL MESSAGE' editor.

example: `<div style="diaplay:block; font-weight:bold; font-size:24px;">`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to wrap any email sent by Ninja Forms in some HTML you can use the `ninja_forms_action_email_message` filter.

```php
add_filter('ninja_forms_action_email_message', function ($message, $data, $action_settings) {
    if ('html' != $action_settings[ 'email_format' ]) {
        return $message;
    }

    // Add your custom HTML here:
    return '<div>' . $message . '</div>';
}, 100, 3);
```

If you are using WooCommerce in your website you can also easily wrap the Ninja Forms emails with the WooCommerce template:

```php
add_filter('ninja_forms_action_email_message', function ($message, $data, $action_settings) {
    if ('html' != $action_settings[ 'email_format' ]) {
        return $message;
    }

    $mailer = WC()->mailer();

    // create a new email.
    $email = new WC_Email();

    // Wrap the message in the WooCommerce template and also inline the styles.
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_mail_content', $email->style_inline( $mailer->wrap_message( '$email_heading', $message ) ) );;
}, 100, 3);
```

If using a filter is a bit too much effort for you then you can try using the ["WP HTML Mail"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-html-mail/) plugin instead.